# How to Force Back Button to Go to First View Controller (swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have storyboard of several view controllers embedded in Navigation Controller.
Due to navigation logic in later views of storyboard, the back button (in the left upper corner, in navigation bar) does not go back to the first view. I am wondering where and how to change this behaviour of Back button of second view only. Appreciate any ideas, examples.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Of course you could implement a custom back button. But there is also a nice way to keep using the default button.

Simply check if the current viewController is still in the navigation stack in `viewWillDisappear` before you call `super.viewWillDisappear()`. If it is not, the back button has been pressed. Then you can do the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    if (navigationController?.viewControllers)!.contains(self) {
        // back button was pressed
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(animated)
    }
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

Comment: Please fix the logic error in code: if it controller is NOT in the navigation stack, then (...). Current code pops to root view controller whenever controller is in the navigation stack (must be the opposite).

Answer (score 5):

The custom back button appears to be the best solution. The code inside your action method would look like the following in swift:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

//Just change the true to false if you don't want it animated.

I hope this helps (if you had not already found the answer). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to say: Prevent Back Button Navigating to Previous Controller and move to first view controller:
You could do this by creating a custom back button - drag a button in storyboard to the top left of the navigation bar, and wire it up to your view controller. In your custom back button's selector write:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a view controllers stack like : VC1 > VC2 > VC3, and you want to back to VC1 when tapping back on VC3, then you could set this code in **VC2** :

```
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:(UIBarButtonItemStylePlain) target:self action:@selector(backToVC1)]];
```

Then, always in VC2 :

```
- (void)backToVC1
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: is it Objective-C? I am trying to do in Swift, not sure how to map it, but thanks for ideas :)